# Adding IP addresses in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, networking, ip

Let's say I have arguments to a function "start_ip_address", "ip_address_increment", and "number_of_increment".

I would like to print the start_ip_address, and then that address incremented by the increment, number_of_increment times.

So if "start_ip_address" = 192.168.0.0 and "ip_address_increment" = 0.0.1.1 and "number_of_increment" = 3, I'd like to print:

```
192.168.0.0

192.168.1.1

192.168.2.2

192.168.3.3
```

How can I do this? I'm pretty bad with Perl string manipulation.

Comment: If you're incrementing an IP address, shouldn't it be 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3, ..., 192.168.0.254, 192.168.0.255, 192.168.1.0, 192.168.1.1, etc?  Incrementing two octets at the same time doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPv4 addresses are just 32-bit integers. Each number represents a byte.

```
sub to_num { unpack 'N', pack 'C4', split /\./, $_[0] }
sub fr_num { join '.', unpack 'C4', pack 'N', $_[0] }

my $ip = to_num($start_ip_address);
my $inc = to_num($ip_address_increment);

say fr_num($ip);
for (1..$number_of_increments) {
   $ip += $inc;
   say fr_num($ip);
}
```

Comment: Technically, IP addresses are unsigned 32-bit integers. Signed integers will have a problem with addition if the address is greater than `127.255.25.255`.

Comment: Right, but the text says, "_just 32-bit integers_." I didn't want anyone reading it to get the wrong idea.

Comment: @Ron Maupin, That's incorrect. One can just as easily use signed integers as unsigned integers. For example, `pack "l>", -1062731776` and `pack "L>", 3232235520` both give the same 4 octets. Only the octets need to be treated as unsigned (`C` instead of `c`), and even then, only when unpacking.